# Pattern for notifying events to Activities and Services at the same time

Tags: android, service, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I'd like to know the best pattern for the following scenario:

1) `ActivityA` contains a button which resets the app data when pressed

2) `IntentServiceA`, `IntentServiceB` and `ActivityB` want to be notified about the event. `IntentServiceA` clears the app's database, `IntentServiceB` removes some files from the internal storage and `ActivityB`, although stopped, remove any pending messages from a given inner `Handler`

Here is my current design for the situation:

1) `ActivityA` uses a `sendBroadcast()` with a specific action (say ACTION_RESET_DATA) to notify the event

2) `ActivityB` has an inner private `BrodcastReceiver` which is registered on the `onCreate()` method since it must respond to the action even when the activity is stopped

3) `IntentServiceA` and `IntentServiceB` also have `BroadcastReceivers`, but they are declared as `public static` and declared in AndroidManifest.xml. This way, they are accessible without any registration on the corresponding service. All the `BroadcastReceiver` do is start the outer service, which in turn checks the intent's action against ACTION_RESET_DATA on the `onHandleIntent()` method

Although it works, there are two main problems I can see with this approach:

- There is an intent filter declared on the manifest which is not accessible to other apps. In fact, both `IntentService` and inner `BroadcastReceiver` are declared with `exported="false"`
- I cannot use `LocalBroadcastManager` because it is not compatible with `BroadcastReceivers` declared in AndroidManifest.xml. That would be desirable since the broadcast in question is internal to my app

I could just remove the `BroadcastReceiver` from both `IntentServices` and start them manually via `startService` from `ActivityA` and leave `ActivityB` untouched, but what if the number of services increase? I would have to include code to start all of them? Actually, I have a few other cases like this one in my app and I'm not sure on how to handle them properly.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Try sharedPreferences. When there is a change in value the activities will be notified.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html

Comment: Do you have an example of how this could be used?

Comment: http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener

Comment: I meant in the body of the post. Link-only answers are frowned upon because the anser loses all value when the links expire/die/move. To prevent this, and ensure you deliver a high quality answer please include examples, details, and other relevant information from links in the body of the answer itself.